# Setting Javascript objects to use Int8 and Int16

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typed

I've got a very large datastructure, part of which shown below.

```
var Data =
    {
        MIDISource          : {id: 0, val: 1, harm: 0},         

        MIDIChannel         : {id: 1, val: 1, harm: 1},         
        MIDISplit           : {id: 2, val: 0, harm: 1},
        MultiTouch          : {id: 3, val: 1, harm: 1},
        TouchFreq           : {id: 4, val: 0, harm: 1},
        TouchLevel          : {id: 5, val: 0, harm: 1},
        TouchAttack         : {id: 6, val: 0, harm: 1},
        PitchWheelSens      : {id: 7, val: 0, harm: 1},
        ModWheelTarg        : {id: 8, val: 0, harm: 1},
        ModWheelSens        : {id: 9, val: 0, harm: 1},

        Fundamental         : {id: 21, val: 1, harm: 2},
        EvenHarmonics       : {id: 22, val: 1, harm: 2},
        
       // etc for about 5000 more datapoints


    };
```

All datapoints are accessed as for example

```
Data.EvenHarmonics[harm].val
```

id can be any value from 0 to 127, as can harm, both being fixed for each datapoint.  Val can be any value from 0 to 2047.  At present I assume each id, harm and val are stored however normal Javascript variables are stored, and it runs fine.

However I also have some large arrays of audio data and found changing these to use Float32 definitely speeded things up, for example

```
const _SineTableMax = 2047;
var SineLevels = new Float32Array(128 * (_SineTableMax + 1));
```

I thus wondered if I could store each point of Data in a single 32 bit location, id and harm as Int8 and val as Int16.  But I can't see an obvious way of mapping Data in this manner.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: bit shift them into a single 32 bit value, `combined = (id << 24) + (val << 16) + harm` and them mask them to get them out? (`val = (combined & 0x00FF0000) >> 16` etc.)

Comment: I think it should be `val << 8`. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: I'd have to constantly add code throughout to unpack them.  I was hoping for a way to still access them in the normal Data.name[harm].val manner, just using less memory.

Comment: @Barmar ah, yes: I swapped val for harm it looks like.

Comment: @MikeBryant unless you're generating distinct MIDI data every single clock tick, 32 thousands times a second, pretty sure worrying about memory is not the right thing to do right now. Even at full MIDI saturation, that's 128kb of memory every second. It'd be _quite a while_ before you fill even a modern mobile phone's RAM at that rate  =)

Comment: Agree no chance on filling memory.  5000 data points is probably still under a Mbyte even in normal storage.  But the points for frequency and level are accessed constantly to update waveforms on the display so wondered if saving them as Ints might speed things up a little.  Before I changed the waveform and sine lookup tables to Float32 it was noticeably slowing down.